# ImageField is not uploaded in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm struggling with uploding an image using Django. Here is my model, where i have the image field:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'  
        ...
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/", default=None, blank=True, null=True)
```

I've read another posts on Stack overflow, and i found that in `settings.py` i have to define `MEDIA_ROOT` and `MEDIA_URL`.
This is what i have in my file:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/images/'
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/anamaria/workspace/AllFest2/festivals/user/images/'
```

And now, in url.py i need to define my urlpatterns:

```
urlpatterns = [
   .
   .
   .

] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

I believe that the path is not given the right way. But i don't know why. How should i do it?(
the user folder is in 'AllFest2/festival', which is my project's root.

```
 user
    ├── admin.py
    ├── api
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── permissions.py
    │   ├── __pycache__
    │   │   ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
    │   │   ├── permissions.cpython-36.pyc
    │   │   ├── serializers.cpython-36.pyc
    │   │   └── views.cpython-36.pyc
    │   ├── serializers.py
    │   └── views.py
    ├── images
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── manager.py
    ├── migrations
    │   ├── 0001_initial.py
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── __pycache__
    │       ├── 0001_initial.cpython-36.pyc
    │       └── __init__.cpython-36.pyc
    ├── models.py
    ├── OCR.py
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you also defined a base DIR in your settings, which results in a wrong `MEDIA_ROOT`:

**settings.py**

```
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

MEDIA_URL = '/images/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'images')
```

Please not that it is common practice to store the media files in a own directory `media` which would result in the following config:

**settings.py**

```
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

**urls.py**

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Also is `user` an app or your project dir? I guess an app, since it doesn't contain `settings.py`. Don't store your static and media files on app level, this is bad practice.

Comment: ok, i created a media directory in my project dir. yes, user is an app(inside my project).  my settings.py is in another directory. I've made the changes as you said. Should my media directory be in the same folder as settings.py? Photos are not uploded yet :(

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add enctype in template form

```
<form action="action_url" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

and also while getting you have to do as mentioned below in views.py

```
def upload_file(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
```